# Overriding wp_nav_menu default arguments

Tags: menus

I'm trying to override WordPress' default arguments for the `wp_nav_menu` function, while still allowing programmers the ability to pass their own arguments. The `wp_nav_menu_args` filter seems like the perfect solution, but their is a catch. The function would look like this:

```
function my_nav_menu_args( $args = '' ) {
    // my code here
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_args', 'my_nav_menu_args' );
```

The catch is that `$args` contains the function call's arguments **or WordPress' default arguments**. Therefore, if `wp_nav_menu` is call without any arguments `$args` looks like this:

```
array(
    'menu' => '',
    'container' => 'div',
    'container_class' => '',
    'container_id' => '',
    'menu_class' => 'menu',
    'menu_id' => '',
    'echo' => true,
    'fallback_cb' => 'wp_page_menu',
    'before' => '',
    'after' => '',
    'link_before' => '',
    'link_after' => '',
    'items_wrap' => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
    'depth' => 0,
    'walker' => '',
    'theme_location' => ''
)
```

This means I can't simply check if a particular argument is empty in order to know where or not to apply my own defaults. There is also the `wp_parse_args` function which is used to merge arguments with your own defaults. However, this doesn't work in this case:

```
$defaults = array(
    'container' => false
);

$args = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );
```

`$args['container']` will still be WordPress' default `'div'` and not `false`.

I know that `$args['container'] = false` will set the argument properly, but then any  function calls that set the `container` argument will be ignored.

The only solution I can think over is to check each argument against WordPress' defaults arguments hard coded in. Checking the `container` argument would look like this:

```
function my_nav_menu_args( $args = '' ) {
    if ( $args['container'] == 'div' ) {
        $args['container'] = false;
    }
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_args', 'my_nav_menu_args' );
```

It would work, but I'm thinking there has to be a simpler solution that won't require the defaults hard coded in.

Comment: Side note: `wp_nav_menu()` should *never* be called without any arguments. At a minimum, it should always be passed at *least* the `'theme_location'` parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the options to be extensible by developers, just add a custom filter to the output:

```
wp_nav_menu( apply_filters( 'wpse119371_nav_menu_args', array(
    'theme_location' => 'primary',
    'container' => false,
    // etc.
) ) );
```

Then, a developer merely has to add a filter callback:

```
function wpse119371_filter_nav_menu_args( $args ) {
    // Modify $args
    $args['container'] => 'div';
    // etc.

    // Return
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'wpse119371_nav_menu_args', 'wpse119371_filter_nav_menu_args' );
```